# How do I diff two different tables identically named and located at two different connections in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two different "MySQL Connections" at two different URLs accessible from MySQL Workbench. Let's call connection one "DatabaseDev" and the other "DatabaseOps". In each there is a schema called SchemaMine. In each SchemaMine there is a table named Objects. How would I compare the Objects table at Connection one with the same table at Connection two using any tools available to me in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Workbench itself, but you could dump both tables and run them through a diff application.